# Can I use more than one Data Extension as Data Filter source?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Why do I need to add two or more data extensions as a source to data filter?

Sometimes we need to add customer or team member email addresses to an email campaign because they are not subscribed and don't need to subscribe to a specific campaign, but they need to receive an actual email the same as subscribers. My idea was to create one data filter which has two or more sources - one data extensions with actual subscriber data and another one for custom email addresses which can be added and removed any time. If someone knows a better solution how to do this, please chare. The solution to select two data extensions instead will not work, cause emails will be sent through API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have more than one data source for a given filter.  But, there are other options.

1. You can run a query activity to add or update you team member email
   addresses in the source data extension prior to running the filter.
2. You can specify more than one data extension as the target audience
   in a User-Initiated Send.  But, only if the target is a data extension
   or list. If sending to a filter, you can only select one target audience.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can use filters across more than one DE by setting up [Data Relationships](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_data_relationships.htm&type=5). Once you have set up a data relation (and indicated it can be used in a filter), you can then create a filter and select one of the two DEs to start from. Now the other DE should also be available on the left hand side.

But, as [pointed out here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000iakkQAA), this approach is unfortunately not reliable.

If you need something usable for end users you'll want [something drag-and-drop though](https://deselect.io?utm_source=sfse&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=sf-se-3). But since you mentioned the API, why not retrieve the DEs data [using the API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_data_from_a_data_extension.htm) and then write your own function to do some matching?

Alternatively/in conjunction you can run an [SQL Query Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm), e.g. using an Automation, and afterwards [run a script](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_create_a_script_activity_1.htm&type=5) in the same automation. Hope that gives you some ideas...